# load or non-load bearing wall?

Tags: load-bearing

Good afternoon,
we are in process of renovating a small apartment that has been gut renovated  in 2000.
We want to move a door position 40" to the right and install a pocket door instead.
The metal studs we need to remove are not layed directly on the floor but have some kind of wood support at the bottom. we do not know if the wall is load bearing or not.

Attached are the pictures.

thank you [![door to be moved][1]][1]
[![JOIST FRAMINGJOIST FRAMING SECOND FLOOR][![LEGEND][2]][2]2]

Comment: There are no pictures attached, you seemed to have picked up only the text placeholders for the images, perhaps through  copy-and-paste.

Comment: It they're metal studs, they aren't likely to be load bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the attic and see which direction your rafters run.  If the wall runs parallel to the rafters then generally it is a non-load bearing wall.  If it runs perpendicular to the rafters then it may be load bearing.